# How to update datat in clients from WCF service after updating data on server?

Tags: wcf

When one of clients changes some data on server I need to send a message from WCF service to all clients that makes them to download changed data. How can I make that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Publish-subscribe message exchange pattern where all client first have to register on the service (subscribe) when service receives new data it sends them to all other clients (publish).

WCF support this when using duplex communication - Net.Tcp or WSDualHttpBinding. You can check complex [artice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx) by Juval Lowy in MSDN magazine.